# Как вывести ответы на вопросы из массивов?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Как реализовать тесты я не разу не делал, попробовал сделать это впервый раз. Я реализовал примерно вывод из mysql массивы вопросов, ответов и правильных ответов, но у меня проблема в том что вывести не получается. Шаблонизатор использую pug.
У меня такая архитектура в бд. Тема, вопросы, ответы(и там же хранятся правильные ответы).
ТО есть справа налево такая связь имеет Тема->Вопросы->Ответы
Только то что я получил массив ответов я не могу их вывести на экран нормально
Моя реализация

```js
const Router = require('koa-router'),
    User = require('./model/user'), //Хранятся запросы в таблицу User
    Test = require('./model/test'), //Хранятся запросы в таблицу Test
    router = new Router();

router.get('/testing/:id', async ctx => {
/** Создаю пустые массивы для ответов и правильных ответов*/
        let answearArr = [];
        let answerCorrectArr = [];
        let theme = await Test.theme(ctx.params.id); // Получаю название темы по id страницы
        let test = await Test.test(ctx.params.id); // Получаю все вопросы, где тема = id
        for(i=0; i < test.length; i++){
            let answear = test[i].id;
            answearArr.push(await Test.answear(answear)); // Делаю выборку и помещаю каждый ответ в массив ответов
        }
        for(i=0; i < answearArr.length; i++){
            let arr = answearArr[i]; // делаю выборку ответов на вопросы в массиве
            for(n=0; n < arr.length; n++){
                let arr1 = arr[n]; // Выбираю каждый ответ отдельный
                if(arr1.answer === 1){
                    answerCorrectArr.push(arr1.id); //помещаю в массив правильных ответов id данного ответа
                }
            }
        }
        await ctx.render('test', {
            title: 'Тест',
            path: 'test',
            thema: theme[0],
            test: test,
            answear: answearArr,
        })
    })
```

В pug файле test

```
include layout
    .container
        h1=thema.name
        for question in test
            p=question.name
            for answearTest in answear
                ul
                    li
                        input(type='radio' name=answearTest)
                        | #{answearTest[0].text} // Вот тут/Когда мне нужно выбрать ответы на 1 вопрос
```

В массивах хранятся следующие данные
В переменной
test

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Первый вопрос',
    id_theme: 1 },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Второй вопрос',
    id_theme: 1 },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Третий вопрос',
    id_theme: 1 } ]
```

answearArr

```
[ [ RowDataPacket { id: 1, text: 'один-два дня', id_question: 1, answer: 1 },
    RowDataPacket { id: 2, text: 'более 5 дней', id_question: 1, answer: 0 },
    RowDataPacket { id: 3, text: '3-5 дней', id_question: 1, answer: 0 } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { id: 4, text: 'да', id_question: 2, answer: 1 },
    RowDataPacket { id: 5, text: 'нет', id_question: 2, answer: 0 },
    RowDataPacket {
      id: 6,
      text: 'не постоянно, Меняется постоянно',
      id_question: 2,
      answer: 0 } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { id: 7, text: 'да', id_question: 4, answer: 0 },
    RowDataPacket { id: 8, text: 'нет', id_question: 4, answer: 0 },
    RowDataPacket { id: 9, text: 'не помню', id_question: 4, answer: 1 } ] ]
```

answerCorrectArr

```
[ 1, 4, 9 ]
```